# Java joda-time TimeZone comparation

Tags: java, jodatime

I need to show a message in the lunch hours, for example 12:30 to 14:00, my message is market with a timezone (GMT -5) different from my lunch hours timezone (GMT -2), I'm using Joda-time library

```
private void getHours() {
    int Hour = time.getHourOfDay();
    int Min = time.getMinuteOfDay();

    if (Hour>=12 && Min>=30 || Hour=<14){
       message = "Sorry we are eating";
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize `time`? Also what time zone is the machine where this runs on in?

Comment: @leonardkraemer I do it in another method, I have somthig already working for weekends `if(time.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY)
  message = "Is Sunday";` but I really confuse with this hour thing

Comment: What type is the time-object? Also what time zone is the machine where this runs on in?

Comment: @leonardkraemer I have this `DateTime time = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);` the time zone from the message is América/Panamá GMT -5 (my machine) but the luch time zone is from Atlántico/Georgia_del_Sur GMT -2

Comment: You should use the time zone you want instead of UTC in the constructor. Then the hours will align.

Comment: @leonardkraemer Ok, and this is the correct way to manage the hours and minutes `our>=12 && Min>=30 || Hour=<14` in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is to use the comparison methods on a `LocalTime`:

```
LocalTime localTime = time.toLocalTime();
if (localTime.isAfter(new LocalTime(12, 30))
    && localTime.isBefore(new LocalTime(14, 0))) { ... }
```

(Nit: this is actually checking that `time > 12:30` and `time < 14:00`. If you want `>=` and/or `<=`, use `!localTime.isBefore(...)` and/or `!localTime.isAfter(...)` respectively)